# Utilizing a socket in an android application

Tags: android, sockets

I've recently made a simple multicast client - server chat for java, now i am attempting to port the client on android.

The issue i'm facing is about dealing with the socket: the socket is created in a thread (as it'd crash the app otherwise), then i use the socket to istantiate an InputStreamReader and an OutputStreamWriter, however when trying to access any object created this way through a button listener, i'll get a null exception.
Also, if i were to put the two readers outside the thread, they would generate a null exception as well, even if i make sure the socket has been created already inside the thread.

I'd be glad if anybody could help me find out where is the issue, i apology for the messy code

```
public class ClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int PORT = 1050;
public static String ADDRESS = "";
public static String USERNAME = "";
SusListenerThread inT;
public int ID;
public int roomID;
Socket socket = null;
BufferedReader in = null, stdIn = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
InputStreamReader isr;
OutputStreamWriter osw;
String userInput="";
public int mode=1;
public Button Bsend;
public Button Bbroadcast;
public Button Broom;
public EditText editMessage;
public EditText editReplies;
public EditText editRoom;
public TextView txtID;
public TextView txtUsername;
public TextView txtRoom;
public connectSocket coSocket;
public ClientActivity() {

}


public void setStuff(String str, int IDh){
    this.ID=IDh;
    this.USERNAME=str;
    txtID.setText("ID: "+IDh);
    txtUsername.setText("Username: "+str);

}

private class SusListenerThread extends Thread{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    public int ID;
    public String username;
    public boolean isSet=false;
    //public View viiv;
    public EditText editReplies;
    public TextView txtRoom;

    public SusListenerThread(InputStreamReader isr){
        //this.viiv=viiv;

        //editReplies = (EditText)viiv.findViewById(R.id.editReplies);
        //txtRoom = (TextView)viiv.findViewById(R.id.textRoom);

        in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        //ClientGUI.jTextArea1.append(joj+"\n");
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        String input="";
        getStuff();

        while(true)
        {
            try {
                input=in.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(ListenerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if(input.charAt(0)=='0')
                //ClientGUI.jTextArea1.append(input.substring(1)+"\n");
                editReplies.append(input.substring(1)+"\n");
            else if(input.charAt(0)=='1'){
                //ClientGUI.jLabel2.setText("Stanza:"+input.substring(1));
                txtRoom.setText("Room: "+input.substring(1));
            }
        }
    }
    public void getStuff(){

        try {
            ID=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            username+=in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        isSet=true;
    }
}

private class connectSocket extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            socket= new Socket(ADDRESS,PORT);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1050);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                e.printStackTrace();
            };
        }
        /*
        try{
            isr = new InputStreamReader ( socket.getInputStream());
            //in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            inT=new SusListenerThread(isr);
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter ( socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( osw );
            out = new PrintWriter (bw, true);


        } catch (IOException ex) {}
        */
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}

private class lilThread extends Thread {
    public lilThread(){
        start();

    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ADDRESS, PORT);
        }catch(Exception e ){
            try {
                socket = new Socket("79.42.49.56", 1050);
            } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
        try {
            isr = new InputStreamReader ( socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        inT=new SusListenerThread(isr);

        try {
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter ( socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( osw );
        out = new PrintWriter (bw, true);

        while(!inT.isSet){
            try {
                wait(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        setStuff(inT.username.substring(4)/*Mi ritornava nullUtente invece di Utente*/, inT.ID);

        try {
            wait(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        interrupt();
    }
}

public void InitializeStuff(){
    lilThread lil = new lilThread();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_activity_gui);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    Bsend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSenderino);
    Bbroadcast = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBroadcast);
    Broom = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRoom);
    editMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
    editReplies = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editReplies);
    editRoom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editRoom);
    txtID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textID);
    txtUsername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textUsername);
    txtRoom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRoom);



    this.PORT = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("PORT");
    this.ADDRESS = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ADDRESS");
    this.USERNAME = getIntent().getExtras().getString("USERNAME");

    InitializeStuff();

    Bsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //userInput= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editMessage).getco;
            userInput = editMessage.getText().toString();
            if (!"".equals(userInput)) {
                out.println(3 + userInput);
                editMessage.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
    Bbroadcast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mode=0;
            txtRoom.setText("Room: Broadcast");
            roomID=-1;
            out.println(mode);
            editMessage.setText("");
        }
    });
    Broom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mode=2;
            try{
                roomID=Integer.parseInt(editRoom.getText().toString());
                txtRoom.setText("Stanza: "+roomID);
                out.println(mode+""+roomID);
                editRoom.setText("");
            }catch(Exception e){
                txtRoom.setText(" Err ");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You should start telling on which lines you have a null POINTER exception.

Comment: 'new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1050);'. Where should the client connect too? You did not tell where your server is running. But 127.0.0.1 can only be used if client and server on the same machine/device.

Comment: The socket is supposed to connect to an address and a port taken from an intent, the values are taken in the onCreate method. If the user has set wrong options, it'll automatically connect to localhost, i've added that part so that i could quickly test if it's connecting to my server (i eventually change the ip to my own).

Comment: As for the null pointer exception, i get it whenever i deal with objects that deal with the socket and the socket itself: If i try to read a line or type a line with any reader or writer i made (since they use socket.getInput/OutputStream() ) i will get the null pointer exception, if i instantiate those two objects in the InizializeStuff method or in the OnCreate, they will cause the exception(As of now they're created in the thread). Same for the !inT.isSet check, it'll say inT is referencing a null object.

Comment: Sorry but i cannot help you if you do not come to the point and not react on things i said.